# separate the Postgres WAL by schema?

Tags: postgresql, backup, wal

I can't seem to find anything related to what I am trying to do. Is it possible to separate the Postgres WAL files by schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  Not only can't it be separated by schema, it also can't be separated by database either, within the same cluster/instance.

To get separate WAL streams, you would have to run different database instances listening on different ports, with either dblink or foreign data wrappers.  And then you would have problems with atomicity of commits.

Comment: That's an interesting design choice, given my familiarity with Microsoft SQL Server. Any ideas why the WAL streams aren't per-database? There's no inter-database referential integrity (AFAIK). Transactions don't support multiple databases, as there isn't any builtin way to query across databases. I can't think of why that would be global to the cluster.